Can I combine first person, second person, and third person in a sentence?
For example:
In my opinion, it's a lot easier for you to stay silent than it is for you to speak up, but we all need to speak up to get heard by others.

What makes you think that you can't? If you have three clauses, each with a separate verb, each verb can have a different subject.  There is a category of jokes where the speaker uses different adjectives to describe the same behaviour in three persons: "I am forthright, you are blunt, he is rude"

Certainly, as long as you are referring to different people.
"I am by the door, you are at the window, and he is near the desk." No problem, makes perfect sense. We're talking about three different people in three different places.
But it's a problem if you shift pronouns when talking about the same person. "He should think before you speak." If the writer meant that he should think before he himself speaks, this sentence is wrong. It is saying that person A should think before person B speaks. I've heard people shift between "you", "he", "they", etc when talking about the same person.

Yes, you can combine them all, but you'd need a specific context for the sentence to make sense.
By the way, your example only uses first and second person. 'We' is a first person pronoun, as with anything referring to yourself. Also, I don't think 'others' is a third person pronoun.
If you wanted that example to use all three POVs, it would be something like this:
"In my opinion, it's a lot easier for you to stay silent than it is for you to speak up, but we all need to speak up for them to hear us."
As you can see, 'them' is the third person part that I added to your example. As mentioned earlier, the above example would only make sense in a specific context, like you talking to a teammate about your coach.

In your example, them is the object of the preposition them, rather than the subject of a verb.  You could change it to "... so that they hear us" to make they a third-person subject.

Yes, you can.

"I told you that he was ill".

When you are speaking, you are the first person. The person you are speaking to is the second person. If you are speaking about someone, they are the third party. So it's logical that you would use a different grammatical person for each.
